# (Is it a set?) Set of all months having more than 28 days.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, definition

> Set is a well defined collection of distinct objects.

Is the following is a set?

**Set of all months having more than 28 days.**

I'm confused here. Because on one hand I think that it is well defined because from person to person its meaning is not changed. On the other hand I think that it is not well defined because if we consider a leap year then February is included else not. **Note that the year is not specified**, I'm you cannot surely say that February is included or not.

> **Set of eleven best cricketers of the world.**
>
> This is not a set because the criteria for **best cricketer** changes from person to person.

So the **set of all months having more than 28 days**. Is it really a set?

Comment: It seems to me that  you could simply distinguish leap-year Februaries from non-leap-year Februaries in your universe of all months.

Comment: What is the set of all months? Does it include months in all calendars used by human societies, or only the Gregorian calendar? What about fictional calendars, or calendars that might be defined?

Answer (score 4):

Sets are collections of mathematical objects. Months are not mathematical objects, they are an arbitrary period of time relevant to the physical universe.

If you model the universe as something with a timeline, and define some partition of the timeline to intervals which mimics the idea of months and days, then the answer is positive. But once you get down to brass tacks you will see that the question, as statement is not well-defined, since there is no obvious way to model this which is truly compatible with our experience (did months exist before humans did? what happens when the sun dies out? etc.).

But if you say something like "Consider $\Bbb N$ as the timeline, where $n$ represents the $n$-th Planck time from the big bang. One day is an interval of length $k$, and so on and so forth. Once you do that, you can easily define the set of all months having more than 28 days. It's just a set of sets of natural numbers.

You can use $\Bbb R$ instead if you want, or $\Bbb Q$. Or any other way which is compatible with how you think about time. If you've used a set, then the collection of "months" with such and such property will also be a set.

Comment: Sir kindly see [this](http://www.mathsisfun.com/sets/sets-introduction.html), here you can see a set of items we wear. You said that months are not mathematical. But in the definition of sets there is nothing about mathematical and non-mathematical objects. **Set is a collection of well defined objects**. Objects can be anything. So we can have any kind of collection but what matters is that whether that collection is set or not.

Comment: Do you agree that sets *are* mathematical objects? If you think that sets are not mathematical objects, then this question has no business on a mathematical website, and should have been asked on a linguistics website instead. If you agree that sets *are* mathematical objects, then they exist in the mathematical universe, where "object" is synonymous with "mathematical object".

Comment: @AsafKaragila: I am not so sure about your  claim. Is the "set" of questions published in Math StackExchange not a set? A standard exercise for first year Algebra students is to compute the number of possible necklaces made of identical stones of different colors: this is done applying  the Burnside formula to the dihedral group  acting on the set of all necklaces. Does that mean that necklaces are mathematical objects?

Comment: @Andrea: Again, what do *you* mean when you say a set? This is like saying that because I am the successor of my father, I am $F+1$. This is not true. Just because we use a word to describe something in real life, that has an analogous mathematical construction, doesn't mean that the two are the same. One is about mathematical objects and one is about real life things. The "set" of questions on this site, is a set in the informal, non-mathematical sense of the word. The set of necklaces is certainly not a mathematical object. [...]

Comment: And as noted by many people on this thread, asking about months is an incredibly vague definition. Will months have happened after the sun died? Were there months before the sun existed? What about months of different calendars? If you want to argue for or against this "set", it's as much a mathematical question as asking if a desk is in the "set of chairs" because I can sit on my desk, and therefore it satisfies the definition of "chair". Which is not a mathematical question at all. @Andrea.

Comment: I'd be happy to hear constructive criticism, I don't fully understand downvotes when they are given silently.

Answer (score 3):

In order to answer your question, you need to preliminary answer this one: **What is the length in days of each month?**

It seems to me that the function *length* on the set of months is not defined (it could serve as an example of something that taking two different values on a point in the domain is not a function).

Let $\cal M$ be the set of months. In order to fix the problem you have, imho, two possibilities.

Either you restrict the question to the subset of $\cal M$ on which *length* is defined, or you replace $\cal M$ with a bigger set $\cal M^\prime$ endowed with a surjective map $\pi:\cal M^\prime\rightarrow\cal M$ on which the function *length* can be extended.

Answer (score 2):

Given that you say that the "Set of eleven best cricketers of the world [...] is not a set because the criteria for best cricketer changes from person to person," then wouldn't the "Set of all months having more than 28 days" also be not a set because the number of days of the month changes from year to year?